Mui data grid jest testing - table doesn't render the columns and rows
I tried to test MUI Grid using Jest in React but the table doesn't render the columns and rows
//MuiGridDemo,tsx
import React from 'react'
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
import { DataGrid, GridColDef } from '@mui/x-data-grid';
import { IconButton, Tooltip } from '@mui/material';
import LinkIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Link';

const MuiGridDemo:React.FC = () => {
    const rows = [
        { id: 1, firstName:'Dave',lastName: 'Snow'}
    ]

    const NavigateBefore = (lastname: string) => {
        window.open('https://lastName.com')
    }

    const columns: GridColDef<(typeof rows)[number]>[] = [
        { field: 'id', headerName: 'ID'  },
        {
          field: 'firstName',
          headerName: 'First name',
          //width: 150,
          editable: true,
        },
        {
          field: 'fullName',
          headerName: 'Full name',
          description: 'This column has a value getter and is not sortable.',
          sortable: false,
        //  width: 160,
          valueGetter: (value, row) => `${row.firstName || ''} ${row.lastName || ''}`,
        },
        {
          field: 'lastName',
          headerName: 'last name',
          renderCell :(params) => {
            return(
                <Tooltip title="">
                    <IconButton onClick={()=>NavigateBefore(params.row.lastName)}>
                       <LinkIcon />
                    </IconButton>
                </Tooltip>
            )
          }
         
        }
    ]
  return (
    <Box>
        <DataGrid 
        rows={rows}
        columns={columns}
        initialState={{
        pagination: {
            paginationModel: {
            pageSize: 5,
            },
        },
        }}/>
    </Box>
  )
}

export default MuiGridDemo

Tried different ways to resolve this but none of them is working
1: change MuiGridDemo.tsx passing props and use disableVirtualization
//MuiGridDemo,tsx
**const MuiGridDemo:React.FC = (props:any) => {..}**
---------------
describe('MuiGridDemo component', () => {
   
    it('should render the DataGrid with the correct columns and rows', () => {
        render(<MuiGridDemo **disableVirtualization**/>);
        
        // Check if the DataGrid columns are rendered
        expect(screen.getByText('ID')).toBeInTheDocument();
        expect(screen.getByText('First name')).toBeInTheDocument();
        expect(screen.getByText('Full name')).toBeInTheDocument();
        expect(screen.getByText('last name')).toBeInTheDocument();
        
        // Check if the DataGrid rows are rendered
        expect(screen.getByText('Dave')).toBeInTheDocument();
        expect(screen.getByText('Snow')).toBeInTheDocument();
    });

     it('should render a Tooltip with the correct value when clicking the IconButton', () => {
        render(<MuiGridDemo />);
        
        // Find the IconButton and click it
        const iconButton = screen.getByRole('button');
        fireEvent.click(iconButton);
        
        // Check if the Tooltip is rendered
        const tooltip = screen.getByRole('tooltip');
        expect(tooltip).toBeInTheDocument();
    });

2 mock the data grid
// Mock columns and rows
const columns = [
  { field: 'id', headerName: 'ID' },
  { field: 'fullName', headerName: 'Full name' },
  { field: 'firstName', headerName: 'Book' },
];

const rows = [
  { id: 1, fullName: 'John Doe', firstName: 'Book A' },
  { id: 2, fullName: 'Jane Smith', firstName: 'Book B' },
];

jest.mock('@mui/x-data-grid', () => {
  const actual = jest.requireActual('@mui/x-data-grid');
  return {
    ...actual,
    DataGrid: (props:any) => {
      const { rows, columns } = props;
      return (
        <div data-testid="data-grid">
          {columns.map((col:any) => (
            <div key={col.field} data-testid="column-header">
              {col.headerName}
            </div>
          ))}
          {rows.map((row:any) => (
            <div key={row.id} data-testid="row">
              {row.fullName} - {row.book}
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
      );
    },
  };
});

test('should render the DataGrid with the correct columns and rows', () => {
  render(<MuiGridDemo columns={columns} rows={rows} />);

  // Check if columns are rendered
  columns.forEach((column) => {
    expect(screen.getByText(column.headerName)).toBeInTheDocument();
  });

Tried using disable virtualization and mocking data grid but none of it is working. I expect the test to pass and it should have code coverage above 90%.
